# Can Sodium form Anions?

Tags: oxidation-state

I am at the beginning of self-studying chemistry and one question I have is quite simple yet I can't seem to get an answer that people agree on, or I am not searching for it properly.

The question is whether Sodium can form an Anion.
I know it can form Na+ but some texts I have read say it CANNOT form Na- yet others say it can.
I am unsure if that is just new information included in some texts and not in others or if there are extenuating circumstances.

Thank you for the help in advance.

P.S.: Since I am here, are there any good textbooks for self-studying chemistry?

Comment: It exists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide#Examples But you should not take its *existence* as a sign that it is *stable*, or somehow easy to make. There is good reason why introductory textbooks teach $\ce{Na+}$ and not $\ce{Na-}$. As for textbooks, check this out: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/37306#37306

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/34111/9961